# How to request all the scopes

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

it seems via cognito I am not able to request all the scopes that google offers.

I am interested in scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.messages` but cognito does not accept such values.

Therefore I am not able to use access token for a chatting.

Is there a way how to handle it?

I would like to avoid removing cognito.
I do not want user to force another log in to request new token.